# VBA in Excel to launch Google Earth stopped working

Tags: vba, excel, google-earth

For about 6 months I have had a functional excel spreadsheet that when clicking a button ran a VBA script that created a properly formatted kml file from the lat/long information in the spreadsheet, saved the kml document, and launched Google Earth to view the plotted coordinates.

I successfully used this on June 6th.  However, today I am getting this error

> "License information for this component not found. You do not have an
>   appropriate license to use this functionality in the design
>   environment"

The KML file is still created and saved, but GE will no longer launch.

I have tried this Microsoft fix, but it didn't resolve the problem.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/181854/en-us

Below is the part of the VBA that launches Google Earth. The "GEPlugin Type Library" reference is still checked in Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications :

```
Dim appGoogleEarth As EARTHLib.ApplicationGE
Set appGoogleEarth = New EARTHLib.ApplicationGE
Call appGoogleEarth.OpenKmlFile(OutputFile, 1)
```

Any help or insight into why this suddenly became a problem and how to fix it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you still double click the KML file and it opens correctly? If yes, try to replicate double clicking the file instead of using the `EARTHLib` library. Check here to see how to do that: [How can Excel VBA open file using default application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921168/how-can-excel-vba-open-file-using-default-application)

Comment: Yes, double-clicking opens the file and using the linked example worked,

Answer (score 0):

Google Earth Pro don't provide a library like the old version of GE. Then come back to the old version if you want use your XLS spreadsheet.