# Open hyperlink within the VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file. In the first sheet there are rows of hyperlinks (Relative files paths = files are located next to the excel file).

In the VBA, I will obtain the cell that contain hyperlinks. How can I open the file which is followed by hyperlink in the VBA? Actually I want to open the hyperlink (open the file actually)

Comment: Are the hyperlinks **embedded** or are they implemented via the **=Hyperlink()** function ??

Comment: is implemented this way: =Hyperlink()

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18922262/4604845

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the hyperlink in the worksheet is in a `=hyperlink()` formula we:

- grab the formula
- parse it to get the **url**
- follow the hyperlink:

Here is the code:

```
Sub ClickByVba()
    ary = Split(ActiveCell.Formula, Chr(34))
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=ary(1)
End Sub
```

[image]

This will work for both links to the web and links to files.
If the link is to a file, the file will be opened *(if not already open)* and the jump will be made.

Comment: This works but it looks like the hyperlink is opened in another session?  at least in Chrome, using this method requires login at already-logged-in websites. Wereas if I just copy and paste the link, no login is asked

Comment: @cyberponk You are correct about links to websites.

Answer (score 4):

As I commented on Gary´s answer, the ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink method works, but **it will ask for your credentials every time you open the link**, if your website requires a login.

If you wish to open a website and have your credentials saved, you can use this other function:

```
Sub OpenHyperlink(ByVal link As String)
   'Escape chars that cmd.exe uses
    link = Replace(link, "^", "^^")
    link = Replace(link, "|", "^|")
    link = Replace(link, "&", "^&")
    'Open default web browser
    Shell "CMD.EXE /C START " & link, vbHide
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `Hyperlink` object reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835563.aspx

You should be able to open the file with the `.Follow` method, or if that doesn't work you can always grab the `.Address` property and pass that to the `Workbooks.Open` method.

Also bookmark the [Excel Object Model Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194068.aspx) for future use :)

I don't think this works on formula hyperlinks, though, so if that's your situation then instead, do:

```
Sub h()
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim h As String
    Set cl = Range("E13") 'Modify to the cell containing your =HYPERLINK formula
    h = Replace(cl.Formula, "=HYPERLINK(", "")
    h = Replace(h, ")", "")
    h = Replace(h, Chr(34), "")
    h = Split(h, ",")(0)

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(h)
End Sub
```

Comment: But the 'workbooks.open(h)' opens file in workbook. I want to open the file

Comment: Please clarify what you are doing and what your actual expectations are. If the file path is anything that can't (or that you don't want) open in Excel, you'll need to use a SHELL command to open it.