# Open PDF file with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I'd like to open a PDF file using an Excel VBA macro.

I have a list of names in the excel file. As soon as the commandbutton "Open PDF" is pressed i would like the macro to open a pdf file from a certain location.

filename corrosponds with activecell.value

thanks in advance

```html
Sub Knop1_Klikken()

Dim a As String
Dim myShell As Object

a = ActiveCell.Value

Set myShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
myShell.Run "Z:\simbeton - Solidworks\bp - betonplaten\bp07 - simvlak ZH Sport\PDF\" & "a" & ".pdf"

End Sub
```

**The error: (my MS is in dutch):**

*Fout -2147024894 (80070002) tijden uitvoering:
Methode Run van object IWshSHell3 is mislukt*

**Translated:**
*Error -2147024894 (80070002) during execution:
Methode Run of object IWshSHell3 has failed.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can Excel VBA open file using default application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921168/how-can-excel-vba-open-file-using-default-application)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `WScript.Shell` like this:

```
a = ActiveCell.Value
Dim myShell As Object
Set myShell =  CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
myShell.Run "C:\" & a & ".pdf"
```

Comment: thanks so far... but i'm not familiar with the myShell function.
Am i applying it the right way?

Command button 1()

Dim a As String

a = ActiveCell.Value

Dim myShell As Object
Set myShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
myShell.Run "Z:\simbeton - Solidworks\bp - betonplaten\bp07 - simvlak ZH Sport\PDF\" & "a" & ".pdf"

End Sub

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I pasted the code as it is right now in my question.  I get an error on the last line.
Did i assigned "a" correctly?
Or... does this not work for files on a server. (external HDD connected over the internet)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `& a &`, dont use `""` around it. It's a variable.

Comment: ah thanks...that was a stupid mistake... unfortunately i'm still getting the same error

Comment: What happens when you run `Z:\simbeton - Solidworks\bp - betonplaten\bp07 - simvlak ZH Sport\PDF\file.pdf` in the windows run window ?

Comment: (Replace `file` with the file name exactly from the cell)

Comment: So the problem is not in the script, the file path is incorrect.

Comment: juist tried another file path on my desktop... same error. strange

Comment: simplify it by copying the pdf to `c:\`

Comment: Desktop is a complex path. Listen to my advice and try from `C:\`

Answer (score 1):

Have you find out how it's done yet?
If not, here 's the solution:

```
myShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\" & a & ".pdf" & chr(34)
```

chr(34) is a "

The difference is :
your command sends **C:\JouBetonInfo.pdf** as an argument whereas
my command sends **"C:\JouBetonInfo.pdf"** as an argument. Note the quotes that I send along. It works for me (Excel 2007).

Comment: I didn't found a sollution yet. I'll give this a try soon. Could you please explain why (and when) one should use chr(34) instead of a ". Is it because two "" after oneanother can't be red by vba? Why do you require double "" at the start and end any way? Thanks in advance!