W11 problems with Google Earth
We utilize Excel workbooks to perform some inspections. Part of the inspection utilizes a Mapping function written in VBA. We are experiencing "interesting" issues with automatically starting Google Earth from the VBA after a W11 install.
Some of the enterprise laptops have the W11 upgrade performed to the W10 machines. These are still functioning correctly in regards to automatically starting Google Earth. The laptops with W11 installed fresh do not automatically open Google Earth.
The process used is the workbooks generate the .kml code of the facilities and then open Google Earth. Both the W10/W11 upgrade and the W11 laptops generate the .kml code correctly. The W10/W11 upgrade machines will auto start Google Earth. Google Earth will open if the .kml file is 'double-clicked' or if Opened from inside of Google Earth from either machine.
This is the current VBA code used to open the Google Earth:
retval = Shell("RUNDLL32.EXE URL.DLL,FileProtocolHandler " & filepath, vbNormalFocus)

Any ideas how to get Google Earth to automatically start on the W11 machines?
If the code is different between the W10/W11 machines and the W11 machines and I need to add code to determine the operating system, that will be a simple if-then and can be done.

Have you checked the return code? Maybe the approach you're trying to use just doesn't work on windows 11 versions of excel due to security settings or something? I'd check that out, or maybe try a different approach to open the file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921168/how-can-excel-vba-open-file-using-default-application

Always worth quoting the file path in case of spaces...

The VBA error return is 5: Invalid procedure call or argument. The filepath is variable with the name of the workbook and a date.

I did try: CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open("C:\Nax\dud.txt") and: Shell("myfile.txt", vbNormalFocus) or variations of these and received the same result.

Well.....interesting. It appears Google Earth does not like .kml files on a network drive (cloud), and wants the .kml on the local machine. I rewrote the code to save the .kml locally, and explicitly used the local Google Earth address. This seems to have solved the W11 problem and the W10/W11 machines are still operating as they should.          "Shell (gepath & " " & filepath) "
